# Saving the value of previous step to use in next step in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, save

For the following pseudo code I wrote the code at the end of this text. But for using `x(i)` and `x(i-1)` the code gets error
`NameError: name 'xt' is not defined`

We have a function here is `def F (x)`.  And  random number `u` which is `uniform(0,1)`. `i=1...N`. we define a `x[0]` as initial point.

```
xt[i]=x[i-1]+u
```

If `F(x[i])>1` then `x[i]=xt[i]`, otherwise `x[i]=x[i-1]`

the steps will continue to from `1` to `N`.

I write 4 sample lines from 1 to 3 for more clarification.

```
i=1     if F(x[1])>1 then x[1]=xt[1], otherwise x[1]=x[0]
which xt[1]=x[0]+u and here x[0] is our initial point

i=2     if F(x[2])>1 then x[2]=xt[2], otherwise x[2]=x[1]
which xt[2]=x[1]+u and x[1] is the point of step 1

i=3     if F(x[3])>1 then x[3]=xt[3], otherwise x[3]=x[2]
which xt[3]=x[2]+u and x[2] is the point of step 2

i=4     if F(x[3])>1 then x[4]=xt[4], otherwise x[4]=x[3]
which xt[4]=x[3]+u and x[3] is the point of step 2

.... i=N
```

the code is:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from math import *

x=[0.8]
N=10
R = np.random.uniform(0, 5)

def a(z):
    return sqrt(z)

for i in range(1,N):
    xt[i]=x[i-1]+u

    if a(xt[i])>1:
        x[i]=xt[i]
    else:
        x[i]=x[i-1]

    print(x[i])
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You do not need both `import math` and `from math import *`. Just use the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with dictionaries:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from math import *

x  = { 0: 0.8 }
xt = {}
N=10
u = np.random.uniform(0, 5)

def a(z):
    return sqrt(z)

for i in range(1,N):
    xt[i]=x[i-1]+u

    if a(xt[i])>1:
        x[i]=xt[i]
    else:
        x[i]=x[i-1]

    print(x[i])
```